# Web Service Client in JBoss

Tags: jboss, axis, jboss5.x, saaj

I have an application deployed in JBoss (5.1.0.GA) that contains a web service client. The library that is making web service calls was provided as a compiled JAR, so I can't make any changes to its implementation. I am working with AXIS 1.4, and things work alright outside of JBoss. After I deploy and try to perform an operation which triggers a web service call, I get this exception:

**javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create message factory for SOAP: org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory**

Can I make a change to the configuration of my application to tell it not to use the saaj implementation provided by JBoss? I want to try to avoid making server-wide changes since there are several other applications deployed there that I don't want to mess with.

Answer (score 0):

In Jboss 5 you have the option of creating a custom classloading file, `jboss-classloading.xml` for your deployable resource. So if your compiled jar is packaged inside your WAR/EAR, you can instruct JBoss to use the saaj implementation in this jar, rather than the server library. This article does a pretty good job of describing how it works:

http://phytodata.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/demystifying-the-jboss5-jboss-classloading-xml-file/